# CallbackFlow waiting for its inner flow to be collected

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I'm implementing firestore in my android app and I was wondering how I can make this code wait for its inner flow to be collected before running with the program. The trip.tripDays in the when expression is getting populated with data a time after Response.Success with my trips is already sent.

```
override fun getTrips(idUser: String): Flow<Response<List<Trip>>> = callbackFlow {
        val trips = mutableListOf<Trip>()
        tripsRef
            .whereEqualTo(ID_USER, idUser)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
                for (doc in snapshot.documents) {
                    val trip = doc.toObject(Trip::class.java)
                    if (trip != null) {
                        trip.id = doc.id
                        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                            val tripDaysFlow = tripDaysRepository.getTripDays(trip.id)
                            tripDaysFlow.collect() {
                                when (it) {
                                    is Response.Loading -> {
                                        Log.d("FirestoreTripsRepositoryImpl", "Loading")
                                    }
                                    is Response.Success -> {
                                        trip.tripDays = it.data
                                    }
                                    is Response.Error -> {
                                        trySend(Response.Error(it.message)).isFailure
                                    }
                                    is Response.Message -> {
                                        trySend(Response.Message(it.message))
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        trips.add(trip)
                    }
                }
                trySend(Response.Success(trips)).isSuccess
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                trySend(Response.Error(it.message ?: it.toString())).isFailure
            }
            .await()
        awaitClose()
    }
```

```
override fun getTripDays(idTrip: String): Flow<Response<List<TripDay>>> = callbackFlow {
        val tripDaysRef = tripsRef.document(idTrip).collection(TRIP_DAYS_REF)
        val tripDays = mutableListOf<TripDay>()
        tripDaysRef
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                for (doc in it.documents) {
                    val tripDay = doc.toObject(TripDay::class.java)
                    if (tripDay != null) {
                        tripDay.id = doc.id
                        tripDays.add(tripDay)
                    }
                }
                trySend(Response.Success(tripDays)).isSuccess
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                trySend(Response.Error(it.message ?: it.toString())).isFailure
            }
            .await()
        awaitClose ()
    }
```

```
sealed class Response<out T> {
    object Loading : Response<Nothing>()
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Response<T>()
    data class Error(val message: String) : Response<Nothing>()
    data class Message(val message: String) : Response<Nothing>()
}
```

One big launch:

```
override fun getTrips(idUser: String): Flow<Response<List<Trip>>> = callbackFlow {
        val trips = mutableListOf<Trip>()
        tripsRef
            .whereEqualTo(ID_USER, idUser)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
                launch {
                    Log.d("launch", "launched")
                    for (doc in snapshot.documents) {
                        if (doc.id == "kJJFEatove5mxw4P70uq")
                            continue
                        val trip = doc.toObject(Trip::class.java)
                        if (trip != null) {
                            trip.id = doc.id
                            val tripDaysFlow = tripDaysRepository.getTripDays(trip.id)
                            tripDaysFlow.collect {
                                when (it) {
                                    is Response.Loading -> trySend(Response.Loading)
                                    is Response.Success -> trip.tripDays = it.data
                                    is Response.Error -> trySend(Response.Error(it.message)).isFailure
                                    is Response.Message -> trySend(Response.Message(it.message))
                                }
                            }
                            trips.add(trip)
                        }
                    }
                    trySend(Response.Success(trips)).isSuccess
                    close()
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                trySend(Response.Error(it.message ?: it.toString())).isFailure
                close()
            }
        awaitClose()
    }
```

Would be cool to make it work without a complete rebuild, but let me know if my approach is completely wrong. Cheers!

Comment: If you want to wait for the code to finish then why you use `launch()` which does exactly the opposite? Just remove that `launch()`.

Comment: Also, I believe both your callback flows are running indefinitely. You never close their channel or cancel them.

Comment: Without "launch" I'm facing a "Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body" in line "tripDaysFlow.collect() {". Also, is a "channel.close()" in "awaitClose{} a proper way to close the channels you've mentioned?

Comment: Ahh, ok. It would be hard to run your code to be sure, but try to put all the code inside `addOnSuccessListener` into one big `launch`. This way `trySend` will happen after adding to `trips`. If you need to run inner collections concurrently to each other, this is also possible. And regarding `close()` - please read documentation for `callbackFlow` - they invoke `close` after emitting the last item. Without it, callback flow never ends.

Comment: I edited my question with a new implementation according your guidelines. Launch block is not firing at all and I got no response from getTrips too. Let me know if I did what you meant.

Comment: Put `trySend()` inside `launch`. This is actually the main point. By putting `trySend` outside of `launch` we send `trips` variable immediately, before it is filled with data. And put `close()` below the final `trySend()`, not inside `awaitClose()`. `close()` marks the end of the data flow, you use it after you sent the final item.

Comment: Also, two more notes. Error handling seems weird in this code. If inner flow sends `Error`, then you send `Error` to the downstream flow and then... process another trip, sending `Loading` and so on. Or maybe I miss something here. Also, you can look into `flatMapConcat()`, because it was designed specifically for this kind of transformations.

Comment: Right, I fixed it but the main problem with block not firing at all is still there. You're also right about error handling, I will get to it when this code starts to work eventually

Comment: I'm not familiar with firebase, but it seems weird to me that you use `await()` here. It's like you use async and sync processing at the same time. Could you try to remove it? Also, how do you verify `launch()` does not execute? Do you have logs there?

Comment: Oh my god, removing 'await()' fixed the issue, I think everything is working just fine now. Thank you so much.